# What speech readers support CSS3 speech attributes?

Tags: accessibility, css, web-standards, text-to-speech

Are there any screen readers out now that support CSS3 text-to-speech attributes like `richness`, `pause` or `pitch`? If there's competition, which one is more popular? Are there varying levels of standards compliance?

Answer (score 4):

Opera is the largest browser I am aware of that has taken the initiative to support these new features.
Check out this snippet taken directly from [dotjay.co.uk](http://lab.dotjay.co.uk/notes/css/aural-speech/).

> The CSS 3 Speech module is currently
>   supported in:
>
> Opera (Windows XP or 2000 only) –
>   support for some CSS 3 speech
>   properties. I've quickly tested this
>   and it mostly works! Note that some of
>   the supported properties require a
>   -xv- prefix to work in Opera, e.g. -xv-voice-balance: right. FireVox extension for
>
> Firefox – support for
>   keyword values of a few CSS 3 speech
>   properties. However, having tested
>   this with Firefox 3, support is
>   currently broken (Nov 2008). Learn
>   more about FireVox support: Technical
>   details about Speech property support
>   in CLC-4-TTS. Note about FireVox and
>   Firefox: Firefox does not parse
>   aural/speech CSS properties, so
>   FireVox support is achieved by parsing
>   the CSS directly.

Also check out this link from [css3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/speech/).